# How to compare switch case with UIViewController as input in swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I have some code in older version in swift, like bellow

```
let initVc:UIViewController? = self.initViewController!
        switch initVc {
            case let vc as ProductListViewController:
                pageMenu?.moveToPage(0)
            case let vc as OrderListViewController:
                pageMenu?.moveToPage(1)
            case let vc as CustomerListViewController:
                pageMenu?.moveToPage(2)
            default:
                pageMenu?.moveToPage(0)
        }
```

in above code `self.initViewController` is parent view controller from there this controller is pushed.

after updat to swift 2.0 gives and error, like bellow

```
Immutable value 'vc' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it
```

Please suggest changes required to fulfil this requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Equivalent code without assigning a value to an (unused) variable
would be:

```
switch initVc {
    case is ProductListViewController:
        pageMenu?.moveToPage(0)
    case is OrderListViewController:
        pageMenu?.moveToPage(1)
    case is CustomerListViewController:
        pageMenu?.moveToPage(2)
    default:
        pageMenu?.moveToPage(0)
}
```

using the ["type-casting pattern"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/type-casting-pattern) `is <Type>`.

Comment: Thanks Martin...really helpfull.